# Chrome extension highlight text on rick click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension where I want to be able to highlight text when I right click it. Right now, I'm able to get my button to appear on the right click options bar (via contextMenu's), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the bg color of the text. Any ideas how?

```
//This block is not working - I want to change selected text bg color
function radioOnClick(info, tab) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName("author");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].innerText == info.selectionText) {
            elements[i].style.backgroundColor="red";    
        } else {
            elements[i].style.backgroundColor="";
        }
    }
}

//This block works properly in showing the options
var radio1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Sending", "contexts":["selection"], "type": "radio", "onclick":radioOnClick});
var radio2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Remove them", "contexts":["selection"], "type": "radio", "onclick":radioOnClick});
```

Comment: not a fresh discussion but there is a big chance that it's not implemented yet https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/kQAmjhBcel4

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that there is the text "qweSELasd" and SEL is the selected part which you want to be highlighted with a different background. You need to split the text node into three parts ("qwe", "SEL" and "asd") by calling the [splitText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText) function twice and change the background for the second ("SEL") node. But you can't change the background for text nodes, only for elements, so the simplified code:

```js
let s = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
let second = s.firstChild.splitText(3)
second.splitText(3)
console.log(s, second)
let spn = document.createElement('span')
spn.appendChild(second.cloneNode())
second.parentNode.replaceChild(spn, second)
spn.style.background = 'red'
```

```html
<div>qweSELasd</div>
```